# What goes on inside a kettle if you can't get to it after the whistling begins?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, water, phase-transition

Let's say you can't get to the kettle for a few minutes after the kettle starts to whistle.

Presumably the temperature of the water inside the kettle is still rising, past boiling point If there wasn't the little opening to let the steam escape at some point it'd get hot enough in there for the kettle to burst (if the lid was un-removable somehow.)

So is it all steam inside the kettle at that point, all super-excited colliding with the kettle walls at high speed? If you open the lid right then does ALL the steam rush out at the same time? (don't want to try it, I think my skin would be burnt off.)

To go *reductio ad absurdum*, what if it's a HUGE kettle with a swimming pool's worth of water, is all the water boiling evenly when the kettle whistles and doesn't it become thousands of degrees before it has a chance to make its way out through the tiny whistle hole?

Comment: "Presumably the temperature of the water inside the kettle is still rising, past boiling point"

That's not how boiling works.

Comment: @fqq Well, it kind of is, if by "boiling point" you mean "boiling point at 1 atm," and if the pressure is allowed to significantly build in the kettle.

Comment: Not clear. Is it all steam at what point? What difference does the size of kettle make? The temperature does not increase just because the kettle is bigger.

Comment: @sammygerbil Agreed it's not clear, but some of your questions are precisely the OP's questions, "So is it all steam inside the kettle at that point".

Comment: @stafusa I don't understand what point in time is being asked about. When the kettle bursts? Is that when OP is suggesting "it is all steam inside the kettle"? And I don't understand the OP's reasoning behind asking if the water in a HUGE kettle becomes "thousands of degrees" before escaping through a tiny hole. There must be some reasoning behind the suggestion - that reasoning is what I am asking about.

Comment: @sammygerbil, Yes, I think that's the moment he refers to. But, anyway, it doesn't look like a well thought-out question, so much I voted to close as unclear. About the scaling up, I guess they have a feeling that it's an out-of-equilibrium system and that a bigger system might sustain larger temperatures differences or something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I boil a kettle, what stops all the water from turning (exploding!) in to steam in one go once it reaches 100°C?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207295)

Comment: If the kettle is whistling, the pressure inside the kettle is only slightly (<1 psi) greater than atmospheric pressure. The temp is not going to continue to increase until all the water evaporates, and the kettle is NEVER going to burst because there is an escape valve by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you seal the pot nearly completely, then you are simply describing a pressure cooker, a method of cooking at high speed that's been around for many years. As more water is turned into steam the pressure inside the vessel rises dramatically and the temperature rises well above the boiling point. You can cook a roast in 1/3 the normal time because of the high temperature.  If you release the lid, then the whole thing will blow all over with scalding hot liquid.  (My brother once released the lid of a pot of pea soup and OH, what a mess it made)  Search on pressure cooker for more info.  Normal pressure cookers have a pressure release valve or else eventually the pot would explode from the building pressure inside. Other practical applications of water pressure include the steam engine. It's all the same science.

Answer (score 3):

As the water starts to boil the pressure inside the kettle rises.

As the pressure rises, so does the rate at which steam is expelled through the whistle. If the whistle is sensiblly sized then an equlibrium should quickly be reached where the rate at which steam is produced by the boiling water equals the rate at which it is expelled through the whistle. This equlibrium is maintained as long as significant water remains in the kettle.

Once the water boils dry the kettle can get much hotter, depending on the details of the heat source and the material the kettle is made from this may severely damage the kettle.

With your reductio-ad-absurdium case the real question is how much heat are you putting into this mega kettle. If the heat input is the same as a regular kettle it may not boil at all or if it does it will do so slowly and the whistle valve will keep up.

OTOH if you scale the heat input with the size of the kettle, keep the whistle valve the same and seal the kettle against any other leaks you will get a much larger pressure building up. The likely result being rapid unscheduled dissasembly of your mega-kettle.

Answer (score 2):

> So is it all steam inside the kettle at that point?

The gas in the kettle was mostly air when you first put water in. By the time the kettle is whistling, there will be gas generated inside (pure steam), and there will be gas escaping (at first, a mixture of air and steam), and there will be *no gas entering* (because of the higher pressure inside the kettle.)

So, you've got air coming out, and no possibility of air going in, and there wasn't much air in there to begin with. Somebody probably could work up a differential equation that relates the amount of air in the kettle to the elapsed time, but I think it safe to say that after a minute or two of whistling, the gas inside the kettle is, for all practical purposes, pure steam.

> all super-excited colliding with the kettle walls at high speed?

That's a fancy way of saying, "hot." Yes. When the kettle is whistling, the steam inside will be hot.

Pure steam at atmospheric pressure *must* have a temperature of 100C because that's how *[vapor-pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water)* works. At higher pressure, it must be even hotter. Alternately, if you turned the heat off, and sealed the opening so that no air could get *in*, then the pressure inside would become quite low as the kettle cooled. Around 2.3% of atmospheric at room temperature. The kettle might be crushed by the ambient pressure.